# i2c boards distance

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, connector, i2c, digital-communications

I would like to use an I2C bus between 7 boards. first board used as main with the mcu controller, Rest of the 6 with io expanders (16ch each), the distance between the main board to each board is 15c"m with a cat6 short cable (each cable carries scl,sda,power) and chained on from 1 to 2 in another 15c"m and from 2to3 in another 15c"m etc' untill the last one #6.

Question is, if using this i2c bus only as binary inputs with these cables description, are these distances resonable and will function in reliable way?

Appreciate your assistance.

i have changed in each board the pup to 4.7k - refference for each seperate board -https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13601
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/SparkFun-SX1509-Breakout-v20.pdf?_gl=1*v60tzb*_ga*OTEyNzI5MjI5LjE3MDAxMTg2NDY.*_ga_T369JS7J9N*MTcwMDI5NTA0Ni4yLjAuMTcwMDI5NTA0Ni42MC4wLjA.
[image]

Comment: what speed do you want to run?

Comment: We don't know what's on the boards. We also don't know if you will wire the CAT6 cable in a poor or good way. You need to define these things better, and there still may be no clear yes/no answer.

Comment: its connected with a screw terminal in each side. regarding the speed, i am not sure as it suppose just to activate when for example an input sensor turn the signal to low, i think a medium speed is resonable.

Comment: its not meant to send data only binary activate

Comment: @barg Medium is not a speed, and connectors being screw terminals are irrelevant. What is relevant is how you will use the differential wire pairs of the cable for signals and power. If all 7 boards have 4k7 resistors, that's already 5mA at 3.3V. Which exceeds I2C specifications and some components that have weak I2C drivers can't work on the bus. Also you can only have 4 IO expanders on a single bus or they will run out of unique addresses.

Comment: its a 4 poles teminal block, 1-4 from left to right: pole 1:SCL=Blue, pole 2: Gnd=Brown+bwron-white also Blue-white, also Green-white(4 wires together).  pole3: 5v Orange and orange-white. pole 4: SDA=Green.  in each board 5vto3.3v for more stability.